# How do I count the number of pull requests I've submitted to a repository on bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

Bitbucket doesn't expose this information in the web interface, so I'll likely need to find it using the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some examples:

https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/tutorials/tutorials.bitbucket.org/pullrequests/?state=OPEN

https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/tutorials/tutorials.bitbucket.org/pullrequests/?state=MERGED

and search for the `size` entry in the response (eg: "size": 7)

Answer (score 1):

The following python code uses the requests library to interact with the bitbucket API. It should print the number of merged pull requests authored by the bitbucket account `my_bb_username`.  Note that you will need to edit `url0` to point to the appropriate repository.

```py
import requests

numprs = 0

url0 = "https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/{username}/{reposlug}/pullrequests/?state=merged"

url = url0

while True:
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise RuntimeError
    data = r.json()
    values = data['values']
    for value in values:
        if value['author']['username'] == 'my_bb_username':
            print value['title']
            numprs += 1
    if 'next' in data.keys():
        url = data['next']
    else:
        break

print numprs
```

If you want a list of *all* PRs, append `?state=merged,open,declined` to your API call.  By default, the API will only include open PRs.